# Input type number to only accept integers using addeventListner

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want html input to only accept 1 to 999 numbers with max length of 3 characters of the input.
But my code is failing for decimal number. For example: 1.2 is accepted by the input.I don't want decimal or float number. Please help.
HTML

```
<input id="measuredNumber" type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```

JavaScript:

```
const measuredNumber= document.getElementById("measuredNumber") as HTMLInputElement;
        measuredNumber.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const input = e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
            if (input.value.length === 0 && input.value === "") {
                input.value = "";
            }
            else if (input.value.length > 3) {
                input.value = input.value.slice(0, 3);
            }
            else if (+input.value < 1) {
                input.value = "1";
            }
            else if (input.value === "000") {
                input.value = "1";
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use attribute like ``step="1"`` to make increment/decrement of 1 each time.

Comment: Use this on INPUT: `onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the value as an integer:

```
let value = parseInt(input.value);
```

This will automatically get rid of any decimals, for example:
`parseInt(1.2)` -> `1`

After that you can do a simple check to see if it's between 1 and 999:

```
if (value >= 1 && value <= 999) {
    // Value is correct
}
```